# Automatically create path between two points via roads in Google Earth (Pro)?

Tags: google-earth, routing

Does Google Earth have the ability to automatically create a path between two points connected by roads?

Comment: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/directions-for-multiple-destinations-on-google-earth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, routing is possible in Google Earth: right-click the start- and destination-places and select route from / route to. In the result, you can choose between car, public transportation, pedestrian and bicycle. You can add results to my places and export it from there - but you have more options if performing it in Google Maps.